# Compare values from multiple input elements on every keypress on each of them

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

So I have 3 input boxes in HTML

```
<input type="number" id="geoOnePercentage" placeholder="Geo 1 Percentage" />
<input type="number" id="geoTwoPercentage" placeholder="Geo 2 Percentage" />
<input type="number" id="geoThreePercentage" placeholder="Geo 3 Percentage" />
```

What I want to do is that as the user types into these input boxes keep checking If their total exceeds the value of 100, as soon as the user types a value that makes the total exceed 100 reset the form.

For example, the user typed `50` in the first input box, that's okay.
Then the user typed `40` in the next input box, that's okay as well,
BUT THEN If the user types a value such as `15` which makes the total of all the input boxes' values combined exceed, then reset the values of all 3 input boxes.

However, I have no idea how to do this. I have learned a bit about `onkeydown` event thing in JavaScript but It's not working as I expected.

If someone were to shed some light on how this could be done, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')];

inputs.forEach(inp => inp.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const total = inputs.reduce((acc, inp) => acc + Number(inp.value), 0);
  if (total > 100) {
    inputs.forEach(inp => inp.value = '');
  }
}))
```

```html
<input type="number" id="geoOnePercentage" placeholder="Geo 1 Percentage" />
<input type="number" id="geoTwoPercentage" placeholder="Geo 2 Percentage" />
<input type="number" id="geoThreePercentage" placeholder="Geo 3 Percentage" />
```